# How to spell the phrase correctly

Tags: translation

Today i wanna ask you how to spell this phrase correctly:

**Wenn *laufe* ich in baustelle durch, dann meine Fahrrad *werdet* kaput sein**.

What are the mistakes i've made? Have i correctly picked up the verb's position?
Does the verb always come into the second position?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean *Wenn ich durch die Baustelle fahre, wird mein Fahrrad kaputtgehen*?

Comment: Or do you mean _»Wenn ich mein Fahrrad durch die Baustelle schiebe, wird es kaputtgehen (nämlich ein oder zwei platte Reifen bekommen)._«?

Comment: Or do you need a sentence for most unspectacular everyday colloquial use such as: *Wenn ich über die Baustelle fahr', geht mein Rad kaputt.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wenn ich durch die Baustelle gefahren bin, wird mein Fahrrad kaputt sein.**

Or:

**Wenn ich durch die Baustelle fahre, wird mein Fahrrad anschließend kaputt sein.**

Explanations:

The part before the comma is a subordinary clause, so the verb comes last.

In the main clause the verb is second, but the initial subordinary clause is the first part of the sentence, so the verb must immediately follow. An additional "dann" after the comma is possible but unnecessary and should be avoided (but that's a matter of style).

3rd person singular of *werden* is *wird*.

The tenses are a bit tricky:
Because the sentence tells what will have happened after you ran through the building site, either the perfect should be used for the subordinary clause or you should make clear that you are talking about what happens afterwards by adding *anschließend*. *Danach* is also possible.

I'm assuming that the bike is ridden through the building site, so *fahren* must be used instead of *laufen*. If it's actually a walk then *laufen* is correct.